# Why does this properly formatted html mail becomes garbled text when forwarded?

Tags: php, gmail, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmailer to send the contents of a form to a gmail account. The text appears as good html when first received but it turns into a garbled mix of html code and form contents when forwarded. Why is this? How can it be solved?

The message is something like:

```
$cuerpo_de_mensaje = "<h1>Resultado de Evaluaci&oacute;n de Curso ". $curso_tomado."</h1>".
                     "<h3>"."Participante"."</h3>".
                     "<p>"."El participante que llen&oacute; la evaluaci&oacute;n fue:&nbsp;"."<b>".$nombre_apellido."</b>"."</p>";
```

And it's sent using:

```
 $message->setBody( $cuerpo_de_mensaje, 'text/html');
```

Maybe it's this 'text/html' parameter the issue?

Comment: well what are your forwarding settings in gmail? if you only forward the message contents as plain text and arent adding a plain text part to the message then thats probably the issue.

Comment: When you say "garbled text" do you mean html tags showing in the email, or character encoding issues (strange symbols)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the forwarding parameter to unicode utf-8 solved the issue.